# How to clear local storage when deleting user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redirect, destroy

I am building a simple react app with a rails backend. If I give the user the option to delete his/her account, how can I simultaneously clear local storage?

Is that a back end function or can I do something on front end?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why would something that is clearly client-side storage require a "back end function" to manipulate...?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts because it'd be really useful to be able to do so :) The W3C currently have a working draft spec to do just this: https://www.w3.org/TR/clear-site-data/

Comment: @DomChristie I feel violated... (kidding, but this draft honestly does seem superfluous.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

localStorage stores data into browser's or system's storage which is local to your system. So no backend process will be required. You can simply use clear() function to clear the stored data.

```
localStorage.clear(); //for localStorage
sessionStorage.clear(); //for sessionStorage
```

Comment: Thanks @Subham Sengupta

Answer (score 2):

You can use `localStorage.clear();`

Comment: Thanks @Rohan Kawade